# Make Connection/Pool Available Outside Main

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, connector, asyncpg

Using the following code from https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/:

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, create_async_engine

from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector

async def init_connection_pool(connector: Connector) -> AsyncEngine:
    # initialize Connector object for connections to Cloud SQL
    async def getconn() -> asyncpg.Connection:
            conn: asyncpg.Connection = await connector.connect_async(
                "project:region:instance",  # Cloud SQL instance connection name
                "asyncpg",
                user="my-user",
                password="my-password",
                db="my-db-name"
                # ... additional database driver args
            )
            return conn

    # The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used along with SQLAlchemy using the
    # 'async_creator' argument to 'create_async_engine'
    pool = create_async_engine(
            "postgresql+asyncpg://",
        async_creator=getconn,
    )
    return pool

async def main():
    # initialize Connector object for connections to Cloud SQL
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    async with Connector(loop=loop) as connector:
        # initialize connection pool
        pool = await init_connection_pool(connector)

        # example query
        async with pool.connect() as conn:
        await conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT NOW()"))

        # dispose of connection pool
        await pool.dispose()
```

How do I make a database connection available outside of main for other functions to use? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "*outside of main for other functions to use*" - but you still have your `main` function as a loop entry point `asyncio.run(main())`, right? Or do you manipulate on multiple event loops there?

Comment: I figured it out. Stored the pool in a context variable that is accessible via request. Thanks.